# Convincing Reduce[] to work

Tags: equation-solving

The following *should* return `True`:

```
Reduce[ForAll[{t, x}, x > 0, Exists[y, x^t == y]],Reals]
```

but `Reduce[]` complains:

```
Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.
```

Any ideas to coerce `Reduce[]` to work?